# HTTP requests stuck in 'pending' state

Tags: http, nginx, web, networking, webserver

Our tech-stack: VPS (ubuntu 20), asp.net core, identity server 4, reactjs, nginx, docker.
Router: Mikrotik rb4011igs+5hacq2hnd-in.

We rented a VPS and hosted our web-app on it with port 80. Everything works fine when requests to the web-app are made from outside of our office network f. e. from mobile network, vpn etc. But when requests are made from our office network some of them get stuck in 'pending' state. There are no traffic blocking rules on router’s firewall and it seems that 'pending' state only appears in our working hours (from 9 am till 6 pm).

[image]

Things we tried that didn’t work:

1. Disabling CORS.
2. Using traefik instead of nginx.
3. Changing ISP.
4. Changing VPS.
5. Turning off antiviruses, browser extensions, firewalls.
6. Using different browser.

Things that somehow solved the problem:

1. Making requests directly to the web-app bypassing nginx (working).
2. Changing external port on nginx container from 80 to 55643 (keeping internal port 80).
3. Removing bearer header from nginx requests.

We tried to monitor traffic using wireshark on client with tcpdump option enabled on nginx container. Wireshark shows us logging messages from the server and it looks like nginx successfully accepting requests then they are processed by the web application and then sent back to the client, but the client doesn’t accept the whole response. Tcpdump shows us that responses are being sent back to the client multiple times with a timeout of a few seconds. And judging by the messages from wireshark, the response comes in pieces.

Screenshot with successful request

[image: Screenshot with successful request]

Screenshot with pending request

[image]

We’re not sure what could be causing this problem so if you have any ideas or perhaps know other methods of solving this problem, please let us know.

Comment: it requires more data to solve: IaaS setup/code for VPS(if it exists, such as terraform), docker-compose settings at least. At the current state, it's really hard to figure out what is the problem from the given question.

Comment: Copy as curl the pending invocations and try it directly on the shell or with postman. Try with another o.s. Share us the result

Comment: @JRichardsz we tried that this way and via Fiddler it's still in pending state

Comment: @sungryeol Here is docker-compose.yml: https://pastebin.com/YK09DT0M and docker-compose.override.yml: https://pastebin.com/k4QVijC1

Comment: @kseen can you give me your office network IP range and ex.searchpurchases.network IP range? If your office network subnet and ex.searchpurchases.network have same range, This issue may happen

Comment: Execute the request invocation using curl and shell. Preferable from linux. Add the -v to the curl command and share the results. Also, you can use gist or github to snippets instead pastebin. My spider sense tell me that is a firewall problem :/

Comment: To troubleshoot HTTP requests that are stuck in a pending state, you can try the following approaches:

-- Check the server logs for any errors or issues that may be causing the requests to get stuck.

-- Check the network connection and ensure that it is stable and fast enough to support the requests.

-- Check the client-side resources and ensure that they are sufficient to handle the requests and responses.

-- Check the timeout settings and ensure that they are set appropriately for the type and volume of requests being made.

Comment: Are you accessing it internaly through an internal DNS? it also could be affected by the differences between internal & external IPs